# Is it possible to change ANSI Console color preference in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, colors, console

Is it possible to change ANSI Console color preference in Eclipse IDE? Currently in preference I see a color palette option but I am looking for something similar as a normal console option shows.